# What is the ANOVA model to use for a 2x2 factorial experiment with units measured 3 times each?

Tags: anova, mixed-model, repeated-measures

If I were to set up an experiment examining the effects of exercise, and coffee consumption on the number of hours slept, what would the be the ANOVA model that I should use, given:

- 16 volunteers randomly assigned to two groups:

  - 1st group will drink cup of coffee in the morning,
  - 2nd group nothing
- Within each group:

  - 4 volunteers will exercise once per day,
  - the rest will not.
- Each subject will be tested on n=3 separate occasions, and the number of hours slept will be recorded.

I find it extremely confusing to get the correct model.

Comment: Why do you randomize coffee drinking, but not exercise?

Comment: Does each individual remain in the group he is assigned to during the 3 replicate (i.e., if he is a non-drinker at the first measurement, is he a nondrinker throughout the test)?

Answer (score 1):

I dont see the problem! You have two factors, `coffee={0 or 1}` and `exercise={0 or 1}` and a response `sleep=hours slept`.  I think you need to specify a protocol for how to measure "hours slept". It is not obvious how to measure that and if you leave it to the subjects, they could use different methods of measurement!
The design matrix would loook like this:

```
  constant    coffee   exercise
     1          yes     yes          four lines like this
     1          yes     no                   "
     1          no      yes                  "
     1          no      no
```

You also need a column for the interaction. Assume coding no=-1, yes=1, the coded design matrix, with one extra column for the interaction, would be

```
 1          1       1     1
 1          1      -1    -1
 1         -1       1    -1
 1         -1      -1     1
```

with each line repeated four times.

In R you would use a specification like

```
Y ~  1 + coffee + exercise + coffee*exercise
```

Comment: Someone else should edit kjetil's answer so that the design matrix is blocked as a matrix the way he intended.  i unfortunately do not know how to do that.  Otherwise my edit fixed various typos and grammar.

Comment: I tried to make the answer look like you hopefully want it, feel free to change it or drop me a note if you are unhappy with how it looks. Other than that, I think you are right. The design doesn't sound overly complicated and the design matrix straight forward (+1).

Comment: Thanks for the edits! Except LaTeX, I know next to nothing about markup. Is there a place to read about markup at stackexchange?

Comment: @Kjetil start at http://stats.stackexchange.com/editing-help and follow links there for further information if required.

Comment: Actually I just marked the text that you already had correctly formatted and clicked on the `Code Sample` button (or press `Ctrl-k`).